# Using NumPy arrays as features in scikit-learn predictions

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm doing an scikit-learn (and also using pandas) project that predicts soccer results based on previous results. For better predictions, for each row of the DataFrame that contains the past results, I took the last three games the home team in that row and stored the results (represented as 1 for home victory, 0 for stalemate and -1 for away victory) in a NumPy array. I got a problem when fitting the data in the scikit-learn classification function, because this library can't process collections as features.

Here's the code:

```
cont = 0

for index, row in ds_resultados.iterrows():
    auxHome = ds_resultados[((ds_resultados["HomeTeam"] == row["HomeTeam"])
    | (ds_resultados["AwayTeam"] == row["HomeTeam"]))]
    auxHome = auxHome[auxHome["Date"] < row["Date"]].sort_values(by="Date", ascending=True).head(n = 3)

    listaTarget = np.array([]).astype('int')

    if auxHome.shape[0] == 3:
        data = data.append(row[variaveis])
        for i in range(0, 3):
            linha = auxHome.iloc[i]

            listaTarget = np.append(listaTarget, linha["FTR"])

        target.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)    

        target.at[cont] = listaTarget

        cont = cont + 1

train10, test10, train_labels10, test_labels10 = train_test_split(data, target,
                                                          test_size = 0.1,
                                                          random_state=0)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(train10, train_labels10)
y_pred = clf.predict(test10)
print(y_pred)
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels10, y_pred)
print(accuracy_score(test_labels10, y_pred)*100)
```

How could I predict the results using a collection of values?

EDIT: A sample of the dataset (ds_resultados)

[image: Sample of the dataset]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of ds_resultados?

Comment: I added a photo in the original photo. Please check.

Comment: Hi Jvsierra, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your data using code to import it in your question, don't add a picture, to create a minimal reproducible example.